# Broken URLs for including js and css resources

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a very strange issues in production servers. In VbScript  application in pages i've linked it to js or css resources. Somehow part of the url, for download js or css resource, connect with some other part of code on the page or in included pages (this is seen in logs already).  Other part can be js, css or html code. 
For example: full path to resourse 
../mydomain/admin/somefolder/css/la-core-main.css 
Instead this in logs i see error (System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value...) with next URL: 
../mydomain/admin/somefolder/css/lead>

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example it's hard to nail down your problem. On your activation of the download links target _blank instead so it does not try to navigate the user to the file directly.

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/myfile.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

**EDIT**: to better address OP's question.

Includes for CSS and javascript only fail due to improperly linked paths. It is possible that you are trying to link the css and js files from the server end of the folder structure and not the client end of the folder structure. Trying to link the css and js files from the server end, you would use the Scripting.FileSystemObject to read in the files and populate them as part of the page. You would NOT use `<link rel""...>` or `<script src=""...>` to connect the scripts in the vbscript/asp code.

If you are trying to connect the scripts to the website on the client end, you need to verify the paths of the js and css documents from the website directly. Open the webpage from your browser and build off of the direct path from the website. So that way it specifically matches the containing folders in the website.

Examples:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Final note: Also verify that your js and css documents are in your hosting web application folders so that you can actually get to them via website.

Comment: possibly I had not described problem fully correct. As download links i means include javascript or css resources on the page. For example: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/_styles_main_.css"
For such links I have a problems.

Comment: Can i see your <link rel...> and <script include> tags that are causing the failure?